# Keep a bot message in a variable with discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot that edits its own message, but I don't know how to keep the sent message.

I'd like to do something like this :

- I trigger the command
- The bot answers, for example "yes"
- and a second later, the "yes" is replaced by a no"

So I guess I need to keep the "yes" message in a variable to be able to edit it, how can I do this ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When your bot [sends](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) a message (for example, `message.channel.send('...')`), the method returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) of a [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message). I won't go further in explaining how Promises work in JavaScript but remember that you will need them a lot while developing with discord.js and it's an important piece of knowledge in modern JavaScript.

So basically, there are two ways to access the message you sent.

- Using [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) :

```js
message.channel.send('...').then((msg) => {
    /* The sent message is stored in the msg variable, do whatever you want with it
    However, note that you cannot use it outside of this .then() block in any way */ 
});
```

- Using [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) :

```js
const msg = await message.channel.send('...');
// Now, your sent message is stored in the msg variable
```

Keep in mind that the `await` keyword can only be used in an [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function. So as most of our discord.js code is in events, you can just make your event listener like this:

```js
client.on('message', async function() { /* ... */ });
```

Just putting the `async` keyword allows you to use the `await` keyword inside of it.

Once again, mastering Promises is really important for discord.js and in general.
In addition to the links I put in my explanation, [this article of the discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/async-await.html) might help you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep track of your message by chaining a `.then()`. For example:

```
message.channel.send("Hello from StackOverflow!").then((msg) => {

    // Your logic ...
    // ...

    msg.edit("Hello!");
});
```